# Apple Subscription RevenueCat Flutter Promo Codes

Tags: ios, flutter, subscription

I've a flutter project which has subscriptions. I also use revenuecat to track payments. For apple subscription I also generate some Promo Codes from Appstore connects --> services --> Promo codes to give them to some specific users. This Promo codes allow user to have subscription for free.

So, to redeem the code I do:

- Open the Apple App Store
- Scroll and click redeem
- Tap on "you can also enter your code manually"
- Enter the promo code and tap on "Redeem"
- Click "Done"
- Appear successfull messagge

At this point what I'm expecting is that I'm subscribed to the subscription which the promo code refeers, but It say me there aren't any active subscription.
I check with flutter-revenuecat purchase package called purchases_flutter.
And I check with this code:

```
final CustomerInfo purchaserInfo = await Purchases.getCustomerInfo();
    if (purchaserInfo.activeSubscriptions.isEmpty) {
      //do something
    print('no subscription')
    } else {
    //do something
    print('there is an active subscription')
}
```